# Excel Pivot Table - group totals at bottom of table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to know if it's possible to structure my table as per screenshot below, with the group totals all at the bottom of the table, not above or below the group itself. NOTE: in this sample the orange section is the actual pivot table and the green section are additional rows I created manually to describe what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: I guess a more general version of my question is - "is it possible to create custom grand totals?". For example, at the bottom of the table, I might just want to show the group total for Beverages and I might also want to add an additional total which gave the Q-on-Q% for Beverages so it would be two custom grand totals with specific calculations. Thanks!

Comment: You can't have more than one total per column, though using a measure within PowerPivot you can define custom totals which, for example, use a different aggregation than that employed for the values in that column.